# Dynamic dispatch of discriminated unions

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a dynamic dispatcher of a discriminated union type that is fully type checked.  I feel like I'm very close, but I can't figure out how to get the last step to type check correctly.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+Qa1ABMAuZAcjnKwF8stRJZEUAhTHPQkUigI2p0sYAJ4AHFAFUQwAPYhkAXjTIAPslb0YAVxAIwchXAAScHgBtoACjhlUASkx0deg-OR9TF63zKtHGEII8gDOYMgAtnBiYqAA5mQYyADaACoA0sTIoMjShsnk3ETkALolZFZicFBwEWQAogAeYDX6ADx58gA0mATEZBlZNAB8jorDyABussBEyDRKHHjItiteRJZQXZy4vh7rm9tBoeFwAJIgYWZIdotJRWSU5PNYwZfhfBdXehB+d308R4CF6TarIXSGL5ga6-XIydzKKxWexkToKcaYMAACygsgA7hRyDR7Mj6FEYvFkud3jCAHRFEo2KEwxwAelZyBAsmQ0FxUCw5NiIDiVOZP3pxEZnxpPzZHN5sigIWQwSgUAg+nMIgF0SFIoh8jFSAlPEZBpARogcp5asVyt0EEaEn0EA22qAA)

```js
interface A {
    kind: 'a'
}

interface B {
    kind: 'b'
}

type Union = A | B

function aHandler(a: A) {}
function bHandler(b: B) {}

const mapping: { [TKind in Union['kind']]: (param: Extract<Union, { kind: TKind }>) => void } = {
    a: aHandler,
    b: bHandler,
}

const aInstance: A = { kind: 'a' }
const bInstance: B = { kind: 'b' }
var unionInstance: Union = ((): Union => {throw ''})()

mapping[aInstance.kind](aInstance) // no error
mapping[aInstance.kind](bInstance) // errors correctly
mapping[unionInstance.kind](unionInstance) // errors unexpectedly
```

As indicated in the code snippet, the problem is on that last line.  The type system knows that there is a mapping of every TKind to to a handler of the type that encapsulates that particular TKind, and we can see on the two lines above the last that it correctly handles this scenario.

I think the problem is that the type checker is not narrowing `unionInstance` in the last line when we do the mapping lookup, so it is treating the parameter to `mapping[TKind](...)` as Union rather than the narrowed either A or B.

We can see that this general pattern should work, because we can create a switch statement that handles every case individually.  In a switch, the narrowing happens which I believe is why this works.

```js
switch (unionInstance.kind) {
    case 'a': mapping[unionInstance.kind](unionInstance); break
    case 'b': mapping[unionInstance.kind](unionInstance); break
    default: assertNever(unionInstance)
}
```

Is there something I can do to resolve this so I can write a discriminated union dispatcher with strict type checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible. Typescript does not track the fact that the index access and the passed in parameter are correlated.

There is a proposal to allow [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) but no word on when it might happen.