Dynamically resolve a function with a record map
I need to execute an handler for an input. I need to select the handler based on the type property of the input. Here is the code snippet.
type MyObjectType = "alpha" | "beta";

interface MyAlphaObject {
  value: number;
  type: "alpha";
}

interface MyBetaObject {
  value: string;
  type: "beta";
}

type MyObject = MyAlphaObject | MyBetaObject;

const getValueOfAlpha = ({ value }: MyAlphaObject) => value;

const getValueOfBeta = ({ value }: MyBetaObject) => value;

type MyObjectTypeOf<T extends MyObjectType> = Extract<MyObject, { type: T }>;

type MyObjectValueOf<T extends MyObjectType> = MyObjectTypeOf<T>["value"];

type HandlerFunc<T extends MyObjectType> = (value: MyObjectTypeOf<T>) => MyObjectValueOf<T>;

const handlers: { [T in MyObjectType]: HandlerFunc<T> } = {
  alpha: getValueOfAlpha,
  beta: getValueOfBeta,
};

const alpha: MyAlphaObject = {
    type: "alpha",
    value: 25
}

const beta: MyBetaObject = {
    type: "beta",
    value: "text value"
}

const choices = [alpha, beta]

const unknownRandomObject = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)]

handlers[unknownRandomObject.type](unknownRandomObject) // error
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Argument of type 'MyAlphaObject | MyBetaObject' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

This works when the type is statically known, e.g.
✅ This works
const alpha: MyAlphaObject = {
    type: "alpha",
    value: 25
}

const handler = handlers["alpha"]

console.log(alpha)

Sample playground link: https://tsplay.dev/wE6KkN
My Question

Is it even possible?
Is there a better way to do this?

Edit 2024-10-29 15:34 ET
Additional context, this is possible with

long-chain ternaries
if-else blocks
switch
forced assertion

I am trying to avoid those if possible.

What... what are you doing with (Math.random() * 10) % 2? That's almost certainly not a whole number. Are you trying to get a runtime error? Please make sure your code is a [mre] and [edit] to explain what you're trying to achieve, if that code isn't some sort of mistake.

(see prev comment) generally the approach to things like this is to use generics as per ms/TS#47109 to avoid the lack of support for correlated unions as per ms/TS#30581, and that looks like this playground link. But I've changed not only your types (which I have to) but what you're doing (which is... apparently... grabbing a non-whole number, indexing into an array, hoping that's a handler, and passing a MyAlphaObject to it), so I hope you [edit] that to make sense.

Apologies for the confusion but I wanted to capture the intent of a runtime value. I've fixed the example. @jcalz, I cannot use rand ? alpha : beta because this is just an example but the real use-case could have N number of types.. I am hoping to create a clean solution without force assertion. if-else or ternaries work but I find it slightly harder to maintain.

“  I cannot use rand ? alpha : beta because this is just an example but the real use-case could have N number of types” Surely the way you choose a random element is out of scope for the question as asked, right? As long as you pick an element and not undefined. But your example still doesn’t make sense because you’re calling a random handler with something that is unconditionally an alpha.  That’s another runtime error waiting to happen and TS is right to warn you about it.  Why would you expect alpha to be an appropriate argument for a randomly chosen handler?

See prev comment. The only thing that makes any sense is you pick a random object, use its type property to select the appropriate handler, and then call that handler on the object. But you’re not showing that. Please [edit] to fix the example so it makes sense.

see prev comments: I strongly suggest you [edit] to use something like this as your example (including the text of the error message and where it appears), since it's actually demonstrating the problem I think you're trying to describe. Does this make sense? Please let me know that you understand the distinction I'm talking about here.

You are correct, this is exactly the same problem.. apologies, I did not know the right term to search for :)

Yes, maybe it's the same problem, but there is a solution, as shown in this playground link as I described above. Could you please read through my comments and make the suggested edits?

@jcalz, ‍♂️ apologies, I seem to have dropped some of the context when I tried to create an example out of the real code. I've fixed the snippet and playground link as recommended

No problem. So, this playground link shows the recommended solution, which is to use generics (because TS does not support correlated unions directly).

That is the answer!!!! exactly what I was looking for. I could not guess the name for this operation to be "dynamic dispatch", thank you for your patience and helping me understand

handler can be the alpha handler or the beta handler. It doesn't know at compile time which it is, so you can't unconditionally pass alpha to it. You have to figure out which you got and pass the appropriate value to it.
if (handler === handlers.alpha) console.log(handler(alpha))
else if (handler === handlers.beta) console.log(handler(beta))

You could write a handler function that can handle either. Maybe you want something like this:
const objMap = { alpha, beta } as const;
const randomType = choices[(Math.random() * 10) % 2]
const randomObj = objMap[randomType];

const handler: HandlerFunc<MyObjectType> = (obj: MyObject) => {
  switch (obj.type) {
    case 'alpha': return getValueOfAlpha(obj);
    case 'beta': return getValueOfBeta(obj);
  }
}

console.log(handler(randomObj))

You likely need to express your mapping as a switch statement to narrow the type. Or you might be able to safely cast at some point, but I'd prefer a switch statement somewhere if possible.

I failed to mention this in my OP but, can this be achieved without forced assertion, if-else, long-chain-ternaries or switch?

@Lordbalmon Pretty sure the answer is no. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57194599/711902 Probably a duplicate of the question this is an answer to

You are correct, this is exactly the same problem.. apologies, I did not know the right term to search for :)
